# Как сделать динамический popup на Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Сделал простой попам на vue, вызывается через метод alert(text), в качестве аргумента передается простой текст.

Теперь стоит задача сделать его динамическим. Чтобы внутрь можно было передать другой компонент и он отобразился внутри.

Например у меня есть компонент **categories**. Можно как-то сделать чтобы конструкция `alert("<categories></categories>")` работала?

```
<div id="app">

    <a @click="alert('First popup')" href="#">Popup</a>

    <a @click="alert('Second popup')" href="#">Popup 2</a>

    <popup
         v-if="popup.show"
         v-on:close="popup.show = false"
         v-cloak>
        {{ popup.text }}
    </popup>

</div>

<template id="popup">
    <div class="popup-container" @click="close">
        <div class="popup-content" @click.stop>
            <slot></slot>
            <div>
                <a @click="close" href="#">Close</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template id="categories">
    <div>
        <a v-for="number in 10">
           {{ number }}
        </a>
    </div>
</template>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<script>

    Vue.component('popup', {
        template: '#popup',
        methods: {
            close: function () {
                this.$emit('close');
            }
        }
    });

    Vue.component('categories', {
        template: '#categories'
    });

    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            popup: {
                show: false,
                text: ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
            alert: function ($text) {
                this.popup.text = $text;
                this.popup.show = true;
            }
        }
    });

</script>
```

Код - https://jsfiddle.net/mezhevikin/du4ca9z7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение оказалось в специальном динамическом тэге `<component v-bind:is="popup.component" :popup="popup"></component`>

В переменной popup.component мы просто храним строку с именем компонента.

[Документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не обсуждается дизайн приложения из вопроса, оставляем это "за скобками", а говорим только о динамической отрисовке, получении HTML-кода компонента.

**это эксперимент***

[пример измененного fiddle из вопроса](https://jsfiddle.net/v2bhcodj/)

Ниже некоторые заметки про использования `.$mount()` для доступа к экземпляру компонента

```
// сохраним в переменную
var Cat = Vue.component('categories', {})

// добавим небольшие изменения в компонент

// добавим "новый" метод для "запуска" компонента
methods: {
  alert: function(){/*...*/},
  runComponent: function(){ // отдельный метод для отрисовки
    // получаем экземпляр компонента
    var cat_ = new Cat()

    _cat.$mount() // <<< ! как будто монтируем компонент ;)        

    // нужно учесть, что прямая передача HTML является небезопасным решением
    // $refs - это рекомендованный способ получить ссылку на html элемент
    // в данном случае мы добавили <div ref="wrapper">..</div>
    // _cat.$el.outerHTML или _cat.$refs.wrapper.outerHTML  
    this.popup.text = _cat.$refs.wrapper.outerHTML // передаем html 
    this.popup.show = true  
  }
}
```

> если это приложение, то стоит обратить внимание на возможность использования [@vue/cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/) - это удобно для прототипирования

### bonus

Как указал автор вопроса (в комментариях и собственном ответе) -  есть родная во Vue [возможность динамического переключения компонентов](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) используя мета-компонент `<component ...></component>`, но это две разных возможности. Первая дает возможность отрисовывать HTML, теряя при этом связанность и реактивность (например: статичные уведомления), а вторая переключать компоненты (например "табы"). Но такое требуется довольно редко, правильным будет - лучше проектировать приложение и использовать изолированные независимые компоненты.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. но в данном решение вы копируете сам html, но при этом если categories реактивный или имеет события, то они перестают работать. Попробуйте в categories на ссылку сделать  @click="alert(number)" . Правильным решением в данном случае является использование component (подробнее ниже в ответе).

Comment: да конечно, component https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#component, я с этого и начал размышлять, но так и не понял логики "дизайна" вашего приложения. С точки зрения вызова компонента, да это решение, с точки зрения вашего примера - нет, там всё вообще не так. Перепишите, может будет хорошо. Если сделаете вызов двух разных компонентов - это уже другое . Почему и сделал ссылку на "дизайн" приложения.

Comment: да, ок... посмотрел на код, и так и не понял, зачем такая сложность... Но вам виднее. Можно передавать данные через атрибуты и обратно слать события. А здесь как-то, не пойму короче...)